# How to implement PHPmailer Ajax Form

Tags: php, ajax, phpmailer

I'm having trouble with a website server I implemented this contact form (it works in other hosting) and is not working in this new hosting. Support Center told me that I must use phpmailer class but I don't know how to implement it.

I will appreciate any help! thanks

The code

```
<?php
if ($_POST) {
    $to_email = "email@gmail.com"; //Recipient email, Replace with own email here
    $from_email = "email@gmail.com"; //From email address (eg: no-reply@YOUR-DOMAIN.com)

    //check if its an ajax request, exit if not
    if (!isset($_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH']) AND strtolower($_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH']) != 'xmlhttprequest') {
        $output = json_encode(array( //create JSON data
            'type' => 'error',
            'text' => 'Sorry Request must be Ajax POST'
        ));
        die($output); //exit script outputting json data
    }

    //Sanitize input data using PHP filter_var().
    $user_name = filter_var($_POST["user_name"], FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
    $user_email = filter_var($_POST["user_email"], FILTER_SANITIZE_EMAIL);
    $nac = filter_var($_POST["nac"], FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
    $phone_number = filter_var($_POST["phone_number"], FILTER_SANITIZE_NUMBER_INT);
    $estado = filter_var($_POST["estado"], FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
    $delegacion = filter_var($_POST["delegacion"], FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
    $ocupacion = filter_var($_POST["ocupacion"], FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
    $message = filter_var($_POST["msg"], FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);

    //additional php validation
    if (strlen($user_name) < 10) { // If length is less than 10 it will output JSON error.
        $output = json_encode(array('type' => 'error', 'text' => 'Nombre demasiado corto.'));
        die($output);
    }
    if (!filter_var($user_email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)) { //email validation
        $output = json_encode(array('type' => 'error', 'text' => 'Por favor ingresa un email válido.'));
        die($output);
    }
    if (!filter_var($phone_number, FILTER_SANITIZE_NUMBER_FLOAT)) { //check for valid numbers in phone number field
        $output = json_encode(array('type' => 'error', 'text' => 'Dígitos solamente en el teléfono.'));
        die($output);
    }
    if (strlen($estado) < 3) { //check emtpy estado
        $output = json_encode(array('type' => 'error', 'text' => 'Estado es requerido.'));
        die($output);
    }
    if (strlen($delegacion) < 4) { // If length is less than 10 it will output JSON error.
        $output = json_encode(array('type' => 'error', 'text' => 'Nombre de la delegación demasiado corto.'));
        die($output);
    }
    if (strlen($ocupacion) < 4) { // If length is less than 10 it will output JSON error.
        $output = json_encode(array('type' => 'error', 'text' => 'Nombre de la ocupación demasiado corto.'));
        die($output);
    }
    if (strlen($message) < 3) { //check emtpy message
        $output = json_encode(array('type' => 'error', 'text' => 'Too short message! Please enter something.'));
        die($output);
    }

    //email body
    $message_body = "\n\n Nombre Completo: " . $user_name . "\n Email: " . $user_email . "\n Fecha de Nacimiento: " . $nac . "\n Teléfono: " . $phone_number . "\n Estado: " . $estado . "\n Delegación: " . $delegacion . "\n Ocupación: " . $ocupacion . " \n Mensaje: " . $message . "\n\n";

    ### Attachment Preparation ###
    $file_attached = false;
    if (isset($_FILES['file_attach'])) //check uploaded file
    {
        //get file details we need
        $file_tmp_name = $_FILES['file_attach']['tmp_name'];
        $file_name = $_FILES['file_attach']['name'];
        $file_size = $_FILES['file_attach']['size'];
        $file_type = $_FILES['file_attach']['type'];
        $file_error = $_FILES['file_attach']['error'];

        //exit script and output error if we encounter any
        if ($file_error > 0) {
            $mymsg = array(
                1 => "The uploaded file exceeds the upload_max_filesize directive in php.ini",
                2 => "The uploaded file exceeds the MAX_FILE_SIZE directive that was specified in the HTML form",
                3 => "The uploaded file was only partially uploaded",
                4 => "No file was uploaded",
                6 => "Missing a temporary folder"
            );

            $output = json_encode(array('type' => 'error', 'text' => $mymsg[$file_error]));
            die($output);
        }

        //read from the uploaded file & base64_encode content for the mail
        $handle = fopen($file_tmp_name, "r");
        $content = fread($handle, $file_size);
        fclose($handle);
        $encoded_content = chunk_split(base64_encode($content));
        //now we know we have the file for attachment, set $file_attached to true
        $file_attached = true;
    }


    if ($file_attached) //continue if we have the file
    {
        $boundary = md5("sanwebe");

        //header
        $headers = "MIME-Version: 1.0\r\n";
        $headers .= "From:" . $from_email . "\r\n";
        $headers .= "Reply-To: " . $user_email . "" . "\r\n";
        $headers .= "Content-Type: multipart/mixed; boundary = $boundary\r\n\r\n";

        //plain text 
        $body = "--$boundary\r\n";
        $body .= "Content-Type: text/plain; charset=ISO-8859-1\r\n";
        $body .= "Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64\r\n\r\n";
        $body .= chunk_split(base64_encode($message_body));

        //attachment
        $body .= "--$boundary\r\n";
        $body .= "Content-Type: $file_type; name=\"$file_name\"\r\n";
        $body .= "Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=\"$file_name\"\r\n";
        $body .= "Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64\r\n";
        $body .= "X-Attachment-Id: " . rand(1000, 99999) . "\r\n\r\n";
        $body .= $encoded_content;

    } else {
        //proceed with PHP email.
        $headers = "From:" . $from_email . "\r\n" .
            'Reply-To: ' . $user_email . '' . "\n" .
            'X-Mailer: PHP/' . phpversion();
        $subject = "ATEL Test";
        $body = $message_body;
    }

    $send_mail = mail($to_email, $subject, $body, $headers);


    if (!$send_mail) {
        //If mail couldn't be sent output error. Check your PHP email configuration (if it ever happens)
        $output = json_encode(array(
            'type' => 'error',
            'text' => 'Could not send mail! Please check your PHP mail configuration.'
        ));
        die($output);
    } else {
        $output = json_encode(array(
            'type' => 'message',
            'text' => 'Hola ' . $user_name . ' Gracias por tu solicitud.'
        ));
        die($output);
    }
}
```

Comment: Generally it's a bad idea to call `mail()` yourself. [Get PHPMailer](https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer) and follow the examples provided.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PHPMailer class can be downloaded from here: https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer (or via Composer if you're using it for your project).

The PHPMailer class is intended to simplify the code required to send an email in PHP. The code you've quoted in the question is an example of the bad old way of doing email that we had to use before classes like PHPMailer existed.

In short, virtually all of the code you've quoted can be thrown away and replaced with a single call to PHPMailer, along with a handful of lines to setup the parameters for it.

So throw away the code you have and start afresh with one of the examples from the PHPMailer documentation.

The examples given in the documentation should be sufficient to get you started; they include setting the to/from addresses, body text, etc, and also more complex stuff like adding attachments (again, a single line of code to do this with PHPMailer). There are also a whole stack of answers here on SO that give examples of how to use it.

Answer (score -1):

Helena in the Else of the If (attached file) 
you have the: Reply-to header ended only with a \n 
when it should be ended with a \r\n
you know, all headers must be ended \r\n

Comment: Hi Milton, thanks you're right. But it still the same not working.